# Excel formula needed for worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is the Excel formula for IF cell D2 is less than 60% of cell d1, then copy cells d1 thru d10?

I have tried the =IF formula, but can't get cwlls d1-d10 to show up.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 365 and you have access to dynamic arrays, you can do this:

[image]

This is the formula in cell C1:

```
=IF(A2<A1*0.6,A1:A10,"")
```

If the value goes above 19 in this example:

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  That was it!  Thank you

Comment: This works even in another versions of Excel Or U may use any of these, `=IFERROR(IF(A2<A1*0.6,A1,""),"")` or you may flip it `=IFERROR(IF(A2<A1*0.6,"",A1),"")`